# Synchronize SQL data over internet

Tags: c#, sql-server, email, synchronization

We are in the process of automating some user data to directly send to our head office.
Suppose, employees from the remote area can record their hand punches, and later send by email to the head office.
We can do the same with automation:-
- Poll the data using some services 
- Email the data to head office
- Get the data from email in head office. Write to the database.

Is there any way to directly send the data to head office without the email procedure?

Hope I can do by public IP, but it will be very expensive.
If I get some single word answers, I can build from that keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You could host a very simple webserver server with a HTTP Post, with the information in the body of the post. The webserver would sit there, and when data a POST request comes in, push it to the database.

You could also add security/authentication, if that's a concern.

What webserver/technology depends on what you know, and what technology you are using. And how you're hosting your servers etc.

You'd probably want to register a domain so you don't have to post to a raw IP.

If this is sitting on an AWS server or something, it'll be really simple to set up. If it's on an internal business network though...